# How can I trim whitespaces in Go from a slice after Split

Tags: go

I have a string that is comma separated, so it could be
`test1, test2, test3` or `test1,test2,test3` or `test1,     test2,  test3`.

I split this in Go currently with `strings.Split(s, ",")`, but now I have a `[]string` that can contain elements with an arbitrary numbers of whitespaces.

How can I easily trim them off? What is best practice here?

This is my current code

```
var property= os.Getenv(env.templateDirectories)
if property != "" {
    var dirs = strings.Split(property, ",")
    for index,ele := range dirs {
        dirs[index] = strings.TrimSpace(ele)
    }
    return dirs
}
```

I come from Java and assumed that there is a map/reduce etc functionality in Go also, therefore the question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with your code. But no, Go doesn't have native map/reduce functionality.

Comment: thanks @Flimzy - then I keep it as it is... learned something new

Comment: why so much downvotes for a normal question?

Comment: @luben i think it was because I posted the question at start with no code and just the question itself - so no prrof of my ambition or attempts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `strings.TrimSpace` in a loop. If you want to preserve order too, the indexes can be used rather than values as the loop parameters:

[Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/PUolmtfK1ox)

**EDIT:** To see the code without the click:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := "test1,          test2,  test3"
    slc := strings.Split(input , ",")
    for i := range slc {
      slc[i] = strings.TrimSpace(slc[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(slc)
}
```

Comment: this is literally what I am doing, but this seems to boiler plate codish and wrong for me. I hope there is a more clever way of doing so

Comment: I'm not sure how it's "boilter plate codish" given that you're only doing it once, and if you need to do it often, you can put it in a function. This is the straightforward solution and takes like 3 lines of code. Not sure why it's been downvoted.

Comment: @EmersonCod "clever" is anti-Go. Do things the obvious way. You'll be glad you did when you have to read your code again 6 months later.

Comment: well, assuming that map/reduce/filter like solutions are what is sought for, OP may have look at libraries like [glow](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/glow-map-reduce-for-golang/) if it fits better.

Comment: For working with big data I would surely look at glow. For trimming a few strings I'd write some obvious boiler plate looking code.

Comment: @EmersonCod You are right. It is most definitely naff, but that is the golang way. If you want to do it properly, switch to C# and use LINQ

Answer (score 10):

Easy way without looping

```
test := "2   , 123,    1"
result := strings.Split(strings.ReplaceAll(test," ","") , ",")
```

Comment: This is fine unless some elements contain a space (note that OP uses `strings.TrimSpace` for each element, which removes only leading and trailing spaces )

Comment: Thank you!!! just that instead of `strings.ReplaceAll(test," ","")`  >> `strings.Replace(test, " ", "", -1)` worked for me. Because `ReplaceAll` was undefined in my `strings` package.

Answer (score 1):

The `encoding/csv` package can handle this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/csv"
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   for _, each := range []string{
      "test1,     test2,  test3", "test1, test2, test3", "test1,test2,test3",
   } {
      r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(each))
      r.TrimLeadingSpace = true
      s, e := r.Read()
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv#Reader.TrimLeadingSpace

Comment: It's a shame there's no `TrimTrailingSpace` for spaces at the end of the text...

Answer (score 0):

If you already use `regexp` may be you can split using regular expressions:

```golang
regexp.MustCompile(`\s*,\s*`).Split(test, -1)
```

This solution is probably slower than the standard Split + TrimSpaces, but is more flexible. For example if you want to skip empty fields you can :

```golang
regexp.MustCompile(`(\s*,\s*)+`).Split(test, -1)
```

or to use multiple separators

```golang
regexp.MustCompile(`\s*[,;]\s*`).Split(test, -1)
```

You can test it in [the go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EKjVwXcAcFn).